# Not able to use two selects in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

Using Hibernate and its query Language. I try to execute the below query in POJO

```
String sql = "select  (select count(*) from Data v where "
        + insuranceId 
        +" in (v.insuranceId1.id, v.insuranceId2.id, v.insuranceId3.id))"
        +" + (select count(*) from Sat s where " 
        + insuranceId 
        +" in (s.insuranceId1.id, s.insuranceId2.id, s.insuranceId3.id))";
```

em.createQuery(sql, Long.class).getSingleResult();

I get the following error

```
2:27:47,128 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select  (select count(*) from Data v where 991 in (v.insuranceId1.id, v.insuranceId2.id, v.insuranceId3.id)) + (select count(*) from Slot s where 991 in (s.insuranceId1.id, s.insuranceId2.id, s.insuranceId3.id))]
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try createNativeQuery

```
Object l = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```

It should return Integer containing sum of counts.

I suppose HQL doesn't support select without FROM clause.